# Derive the Derivative of a Lagrange Multiplier Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Sorry for a tedious question, but I really eager to know how to derive these equations.

Now I'm reading a [paper](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/0067-0049/225/1/4) and stuck in differentiating a Lagrangian multiplier equation.

The given Lagrangian equation is as below

$$G(X) = Q(X) + \sum_{j=1}^m \pi_{j}\left( -\sum_{i} a_{ij}x_{i} + b_{j}\right) \qquad (22)$$

here, $\pi_{j}$ is the Lagrangian multiplier and $Q(X)$ is the quadratic approximation of $F(X)$:

$$Q(X) = \left.F(X) \right\rvert_{X=Y} + \left.{\sum_{i} {{\partial F} \over {\partial x_{i}}} }\right\rvert_{X=Y} \Delta_i + \left.{\frac 12 \sum_i , \sum_k , {{\partial^2 F} \over {\partial x_i \partial x_k}}}\right\rvert_{X=Y} \Delta_i \Delta_k \qquad (21)$$

with $\Delta_i = x_i - y_i $.

$x_i$ is improved value(mole number here) and $y_i$ is initial value.

$$F(Y) = \sum_{i=1}^n y_i \left [c_i + ln {\frac {y_i}{\bar y}} \right] \qquad (20)$$

$$f_i (Y) = y_i \left [ c_i + ln \frac{y_i}{\bar y} \right ] \qquad (19)$$

And $c_i = \frac {g_i^0 (T)}{RT} + ln P$ is treated as a constant. Then, $\bar x = \textstyle \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i $

The constraint function is

$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij} y_i = b_j \quad (j = 1, 2, ..., m)  \qquad (17) $$

From the paper, $x_i$ is given from the first equation(Lagrangian multiplier equation).

with $\pi_j$.

$$ x_i = -f_i (Y) + \left ( \frac {y_i}{\bar y} \right ) \bar x + \left ( \sum_{j=1}^{m} \pi_j a_{ij} \right ) y_i  \qquad (23) $$

$$\sum_{j=1}^{m} \pi_j \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{ij} y_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i  \qquad (24) $$

I think these two values, $x_i ,\ \pi_j$ are derived from $ \frac {\partial G}{\partial {x_i} } = 0 $, but I couldn't to derive these equations.

Any hint would help me.

---

I solved this for $x_i$ and I'll write it separately.

Comment: Can you start by writing down an expression for $Q(x)$? There is so much notation in this question that it is hard to tell what it is supposed to be. It may also help to write them as $G(x) = Q(x) - \pi^T(A^Tx - b)$

Comment: @whpowell96 Thank you for comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative is to forget about indices and use instead vectors for a more concise derivation.
Consider the scalar-valued function
$
f(\mathbf{y}) = \mathbf{y}:\mathbf{k}
$
where
$
\mathbf{k}
= \mathbf{c} + 
\ln \frac{\mathbf{y}}{\hat{y}\mathbf{1}}
$

The colon operator ':' denotes the inner product between vectors and the division is meant elementwise

As you disovered, the gradient of $f$ is
$\mathbf{g} = \mathbf{k}$
and the Hessian is
$\mathbf{H}
= \operatorname{Diag}
\left(
\frac{\mathbf{1}}{\mathbf{y}}
\right)
-
\frac{1}{\bar{y}}
\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^T
$.

An important observation is that
$\mathbf{Hy}=\mathbf{0}$.

The second-order approximation of the function $f$ at $\mathbf{x}$ is
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(\mathbf{x})
&=& 
f(\mathbf{y})+
\mathbf{g}^T(\mathbf{x-y})+
\frac12
\left( \mathbf{x-y} \right)^T
\mathbf{H}
\left( \mathbf{x-y} \right) \\
&=&
\mathbf{k}:\mathbf{x}+
\frac12
\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{H} \mathbf{x}
+ Cst
\end{eqnarray*}

The Lagrangian takes the following form
$$
l(\mathbf{x})
=
f(\mathbf{x})
- \mathbf{\pi}:
(\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{b})
$$

The gradient of the Lagrangian is
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial l}{\partial \mathbf{x}}
&=&
\mathbf{k}
+
\mathbf{Hx}
-
\mathbf{A} \mathbf{\pi} \\
&=&
\mathbf{k}
+
\frac{\mathbf{x}}{\mathbf{y}}
-
\frac{\bar{x}}{\bar{y}}\mathbf{1}
-
\mathbf{A} \mathbf{\pi}
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @whpowell96 for giving me a courage to tackle this problem.

**1. First derivative of F(X)**

$$F(X) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i \left\{ c_i + ln \frac{x_i}{\bar x} \right\}
       = \sum_{i=1}^{n} c_i x_i + 
         \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i ln x_i -
         \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i ln \bar x $$

$$\frac{\partial F(X)}{\partial x_i} 
= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \left\{ \sum_{i=1}^{n} c_i x_i \right\} 
   $$$$+ \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \left\{ \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i ln x_i \right\} -
    \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \left\{ \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i ln \bar x \right\}$$

There are three terms in right hand side of the equation.

$$$$

- The 1st term
  $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \left\{ \sum_{i=1}^{n} c_i x_i \right\}  
  = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \left\{ c_i x_i \right\} = c_i$$

  Because any element $c_j x_j$ for $j \neq i $ would be zero above.

$$$$

- The 2nd term
  $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \left\{ \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i ln x_i \right\} 
  = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \left\{ x_i ln x_i \right\}
  = \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_i} ln x_i + x_i \frac{\partial ln x_i}{\partial x_i} 
  = ln x_i + x_i \cdot \frac{1}{x_i}
  = ln x_i + 1$$

$$$$

- The 3rd term
  $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \left\{ \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i ln \bar x \right\}
  = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \left\{ ln \bar x \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i  \right\}
  = \frac{\partial ln \bar x}{\partial x_i} \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i  
   + ln \bar x  \cdot \frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i $$
  $$= \frac{\partial ln \bar x}{\partial \bar x} \cdot \frac{\partial \bar x}{\partial x_i} \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i + ln \bar x \cdot 1 
  =\frac{1}{\bar x} \cdot 1 \cdot \bar x + ln \bar x = \ln \bar x + 1$$

So,

$$\frac{\partial F(X)}{\partial x_i} = \left\{ c_i \right\} + \left\{ ln x_i + 1 \right\} - \left\{ \ln \bar x + 1 \right\} = c_i + ln x_i - ln \bar x$$

or from the definition of $f_i (X)$

$$\frac{\partial F(X)}{\partial x_i} = c_i + ln \frac{x_i}{\bar x} = \frac{f_i (X)}{x_i}$$

**2. Second derivative of F(X)**
$$\frac{\partial^2 F(X)}{\partial x_i \partial x_k}=
\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial^2 F(X)}{\partial x_i^2} = \frac{1}{x_i} - \frac{1}{\bar x},  & \text{if $k=i$ } \\
- \frac{1}{\bar x}, & \text{if $k \neq i$}
\end{cases}$$

At this moment, think about the 2nd order Taylor expansion for the 2 variable function at $Y = \left(y_1, y_2 \right)$.

$$F\left(x_1, x_2\right) \approx p_2 \left(x_1, x_2 \right) = F\left(y_1, y_2\right) + F_{x_1} \left(y_1, y_2\right) \left(x_1 - y_1\right) + F_{x_2} \left(y_1, y_2\right) \left(x_2 - y_2\right)+ \frac{1}{2} \left[ F_{x_1 x_1} \left(y_1, y_2\right) \left(x_1 - y_1\right)^2 + 2F_{x_1 x_2} \left(y_1, y_2\right) \left(x_1 - y_1\right) \left(x_2 - y_2\right) + F_{x_2 x_2} \left(y_1, y_2\right) \left(x_2 - y_2\right)^2\right]$$

Expanding the concept to multivariable function, there are two terms relating $x_i$ and residuals for the 2nd derivative above.

For multivariable function regarding to x_i only,

$$\frac{1}{2} \sum_i \sum_k \left.\frac{\partial^2 F(X)}{\partial x_i \partial x_k}\right\rvert_{X=Y} \Delta_i \Delta_k = $$

$$\frac{1}{2} \left[ \left.F_{x_i x_i}\right\rvert_{X=Y} \left( x_i - y_i \right)^2 + 2 \sum_{k\neq i} \left.F_{x_i x_k}\right\rvert_{X=Y} \left( x_i - y_i \right) \left( x_k - y_k \right) + ... \right]$$

$$$$
Here, '$...$' is residual not related to $x_i$
$$$$

$$= \frac{1}{2} \left[ \left.\left( \frac{1}{x_i} - \frac{1}{\bar x} \right)\right\rvert_{X=Y} \left( x_i^2 - 2x_i y_i + y_i^2 \right) + 2 \sum_{k\neq i} \left.\left(-\frac{1}{\bar x}\right)\right\rvert_{X=Y} \left( x_i x_k - x_i y_k - x_k y_i + y_i y_k \right) + ...\right] $$

$$= \frac{1}{2} \left[ \left( \frac{1}{y_i} - \frac{1}{\bar y} \right) \left( x_i^2 - 2x_i y_i + y_i^2 \right) + 2 \sum_{k\neq i} \left(-\frac{1}{\bar y}\right) \left( x_i x_k - x_i y_k - x_k y_i + y_i y_k \right) + ...\right]$$

$$= \frac{1}{2}\left[ \frac{x_i^2}{y_i} - 2x_i + y_i - \frac{x_i^2}{\bar y} + 2 \frac{x_i y_i}{\bar y} - \frac{y_i^2}{\bar y} - 2 \sum_{k\neq i}\frac{x_i x_k}{\bar y} + 2 \sum_{k\neq i}\frac{x_i y_k}{\bar y} + 2 \sum_{k\neq i}\frac{x_k y_i}{\bar y} - 2 \sum_{k\neq i}\frac{y_i y_k}{\bar y} + ... \right]$$

$$$$
Here, $k\neq i$ means $k=1$ except $k=i$.
$$$$

$$= \frac{x_i^2}{2 y_i} - x_i + \frac{y_i}{2} - \frac{x_i^2}{2 \bar y} + \frac{x_i y_i}{\bar y} - \frac{y_i^2}{2\bar y} -  \sum_{k\neq i}\frac{x_i x_k}{\bar y} + \sum_{k\neq i}\frac{x_i y_k}{\bar y} + \sum_{k\neq i}\frac{x_k y_i}{\bar y} - \sum_{k\neq i}\frac{y_i y_k}{\bar y} + ... $$
$$$$
**3. Differential of the 2nd derivative of F(X)**

Therefore
$$$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \left[ \frac{1}{2} \sum_i \sum_k \left.\frac{\partial^2 F(X)}{\partial x_i \partial x_k}\right\rvert_{X=Y} \Delta_i \Delta_k \right] = $$

$$\frac{x_i}{y_i} - 1 - \frac{x_i}{\bar y} + \frac{y_i}{\bar y} - \sum_{k\neq i}\frac{x_k}{\bar y} + \sum_{k\neq i}\frac{y_k}{\bar y}$$

$$$$
Here, for the 3rd & 5th term in RHS
$$\frac{x_i}{\bar y} + \sum_{k\neq i}\frac{x_k}{\bar y} = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{x_k}{\bar y} = \frac{\bar x}{\bar y}$$
$$$$
And, for the 4th & 6th term in RHS
$$\frac{y_i}{\bar y} + \sum_{k\neq i}\frac{y_k}{\bar y} = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{y_k}{\bar y} = 1$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \left[ \frac{1}{2} \sum_i \sum_k \left.\frac{\partial^2 F(X)}{\partial x_i \partial x_k}\right\rvert_{X=Y} \Delta_i \Delta_k \right] = \frac{x_i}{y_i} - 1  - \frac{\bar x}{\bar y} + 1 = \frac{x_i}{y_i} - \frac{\bar x}{\bar y}$$
$$$$

**4. Differential of G(X)**

$$G(X) = Q(X) + \sum_j \pi_j \left( - \sum_i a_{ij} x_i + b_j \right) $$
$$0 = \frac{\partial G(X)}{\partial x_i} = \frac{\partial Q(X)}{\partial x_i} - \sum_j \pi_j a_{ij}$$
$$= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left\{ \left.F(X)\right\rvert_{X=Y} \right\} + \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \left\{ \left.\frac{\partial F(X)}{\partial x_i}\right\rvert_{X=Y} \Delta_i \right\} + \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \left\{ \frac{1}{2} \sum_i \sum_k \left.\frac{\partial^2 F(X)}{\partial x_i \partial x_k}\right\rvert_{X=Y} \Delta_i \Delta_k \right\} - \sum_j \pi_j a_{ij} $$

$$= 0 + \frac{f_i (Y)}{y_i} + \frac{x_i}{y_i} - \frac{\bar x}{\bar y} - \sum_j \pi_j a_{ij} $$

$$\rightarrow \frac{x_i}{y_i} = -\frac{f_i (Y)}{y_i} + \frac{\bar x}{\bar y} + \sum_j \pi_j a_{ij}$$

$$\rightarrow x_i = -f_i (Y) + \left( \frac{y_i}{\bar y}\right)\bar x + \left(\sum_j \pi_j a_{ij}\right) y_i$$

This result is the same as equation (23)

Comment: There was the original paper written by [white, 1958](https://www.fkit.unizg.hr/_download/repository/white1958.pdf) that describes the intermediate steps in formula derivation.